# $l$-Sylow subgroups of $SL_3(\Bbb{F}_p)$ are cyclic for $l|p^2 + p + 1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $l > 3$ be a prime dividing $p^2 + p + 1$, for $p$ a prime number. I wish to prove that all Sylow $l$-subgroups of $G = SL_3(\Bbb{F}_p)$ are cyclic.

First, using the surjective group homomorphism $\det : GL_3(\Bbb{F}_p) \to \Bbb{F}_p^\times$, we compute that the order of $G$ is given by
$$\#G = \frac{(p^3- 1)(p^3 - p)(p^3 - p^2)}{p-1} = p^3(p-1)^2(p+1)(p^2 + p +1). $$
Then, by  number theory considerations I conclude that $l  > 3$ divides none of $p, p-1$ or $p+1$.

> > **My question is:** I can exhibit a cyclic subgroup  $H \subseteq g$ of order $p^2 + p+1$. However, why is this enough to prove that all $l$-Sylow subgroups are cyclic? Does this follow from the fact that any $l$-Sylow subgroup is contained in $H$, and if so how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know that $p^2+p+1$ is co-prime to the other factors: $p-1$, $p$, and $p+1$, the order of $l$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H$ are the same.

On the other hand, an $l$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ is also an $l$-subgroup of $G$, hence a subgroup of an $l$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

So the $l$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ is exactly the $l$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $l$ divides $p^2 + p + 1$ and none of $p-1$, $p$, or $p+1$, it follows that any $l$-Sylow subgroup of the cyclic group $H$ is also an $l$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. The $l$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are all conjugate by the Sylow Theorems, so $G$ contains a cyclic $l$-Sylow subgroup.